# DataFilter Interferes with AutoComplete on UltraCombo Inside UltraGrid

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

I have an UltraCombo set inside an UltraGrid, with AutoComplete set to "Suggest". The UltraCombo has a DisplayMember of "Name" and a ValueMember of "ID". What I've found is that when I attach a DataFilter to the UltraCombo (I'd like to make it appear blank when the value is zero), if they type a digit that happens to match an ID and also starts a Name, it will do the autocomplete, but the underlying value is never changed. So no AfterUpdate or CellChange is triggered, and when you leave the cell, it reverts to blank. How can I have AutoComplete work and still show the zero-value as blank? Here's my code (Note, if you comment out the line where UltraCombo1.DataFilter is set, updates work fine, but you lose the DataFiltering):

```
Imports Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid
Imports Infragistics.Win

Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Dim datatableCombo = New DataTable
        datatableCombo.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
        datatableCombo.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
        datatableCombo.Rows.Add({1, "123"})
        datatableCombo.Rows.Add({2, "234"})
        datatableCombo.Rows.Add({3, "456"})

        UltraCombo1.DataFilter = New MyDataFilter()
        UltraCombo1.DataSource = datatableCombo
        UltraCombo1.ValueMember = "ID"
        UltraCombo1.DisplayMember = "Name"

        Dim position As Integer = 0
        UltraCombo1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("ID").Hidden = False
        UltraCombo1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("ID").Header.VisiblePosition = position
        position += 1
        UltraCombo1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("Name").Hidden = False
        UltraCombo1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("Name").Header.VisiblePosition = position
        position += 1

        Dim datatableGrid = New DataTable
        datatableGrid.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
        datatableGrid.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
        UltraGrid1.DataSource = datatableGrid

        UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.GroupByBox.Hidden = True
        UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.RowSelectors = DefaultableBoolean.True
        UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowAddNew = AllowAddNew.TemplateOnBottom

        UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("ID").EditorComponent = UltraCombo1
        UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("ID").CellClickAction = CellClickAction.EditAndSelectText
        UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("ID").Style = ColumnStyle.DropDownValidate
    End Sub

    Public Class MyDataFilter
        Implements Infragistics.Win.IEditorDataFilter

        Public Function Convert(ByVal convertArgs As Infragistics.Win.EditorDataFilterConvertArgs) As Object Implements Infragistics.Win.IEditorDataFilter.Convert
            ' Shouldn't affect anything?
            convertArgs.Handled = False
            Return Nothing
        End Function
    End Class

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in Infragistics 11.2. I'm not sure at what point they fixed it, but it doesn't happen with version 15.2.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set AutoCompleteMode to the grid column and not to the Ultracombo. When UltraCombo is set as EditorComponent the grid uses its editor. If you set AutoCompleteMode to the combo in this situation it does not have any effect in the grid.
If you set AutoCompleteMode to the grid's column you will not need also to set DataFilter to the combo.